# Is it possible to add fancybox to portfoliojs image gallery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox, portfolio

Plugin [portfoliojs](http://portfoliojs.com) was my choice for creating a carousel-style portfolio. However, I have discovered that there is no zoom functionality built into the plug in. Due to relative complexity of the jquery code, I am at a loss how to manually add zoom (more precisely, fancybox) functionality to the gallery. The "lightbox=true" initialization option merely dims the other images in the gallery, but does not zoom the image of choice.

Ideally, I would like to add fancybox functionality to my gallery, e.g. my html would look like this:

```
    <div id="gallery">
        <a href="someimage.jpg" class="fancybox"> <img src="someimage.jpg></img> </a>              
        <a href="someimage2.jpg" class="fancybox"> <img src="someimage2.jpg></img> </a>
    </div>
```

However, the gallery in portfoliojs only works when  is child element of  ( with no  level in between):

```
   <div id="gallery">
         <img src="someimage.jpg></img>               
         <img src="someimage2.jpg></img>
    </div>
```

I have tried to wrap the `<img>`elements into `<a>` but it did not work.

Is there a way I could combine the functionality of two plugins ( portfoliojs and fancybox) without significant code rewriting? What would the alternative be?

Comment: Does `src="someimage.jpg"` in `img` actually point to the big image?

Comment: in my code, at this point, it does ( the images in the gallery get formatted to fit the carousel to be smaller, but the source files are the same for gallery and zoomed images).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I would do.

Having an html like this :

```
<div id="gallery">
    <img src="images/01.jpg" alt=""/>
    <img src="images/02.jpg" alt=""/>
</div>
```

where `src` attribute points to the image to be shown in fancybox, use this code :

```
var images = [];
$("#gallery").find("img").each(function(i){
    images[i] = $(this).attr("src");
    $(this).bind("click", function(){
        $.fancybox(images,{
            index: i
        });
    })
});
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/KxaZm/)**

**NOTE**: You could use `.on()` (preferred) instead of `.bind()` :

```
$(this).on("click", function(){ ...
```

it requires jQuery 1.7+ though. See updated **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/KxaZm/1/)**

Comment: Thank you so much, @JFK, this is exactly what I needed, plus a very elegant solution!